# How to send an email when item is added to Cosmos DB with Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, sendgrid

I want to have a Cosmos DB trigger which gives me the added document, which I can use to send an email via Sendgrid.

Now I've already added the Cosmos DB trigger, and also the Sendgrid output, but I don't really know how to get the added document from the Cosmos DB.

Can anyone help?

```
// function.json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "restaurant",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "connection-string",
      "databaseName": "database-name",
      "collectionName": "collection-name",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey": "SENDGRID_API_KEY",
      "from": "from",
      "to": "{customerEmail}",
      "subject": "",
      "text": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with Logic Apps. The new Logic Apps Standard has new connectors for Cosmos DB. There you could use the [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-cosmos-db?tabs=consumption) to listen for new items and then add [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/) to send the email.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just checked Logic Apps, and it seems the Cosmos DB trigger is only available for the Standard pricing model. I'm just experimenting a bit, so I'd like to keep with the Consumption pricing model, where the Cosmos DB trigger isn't available yet unfortunately.

Comment: @RicardodeVries I would caution anyone using Azure Logic Apps for anything critical anyway. Even the simplest task is an absolute pain using Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=javascript

```js
module.exports = function (context, restaurant) {
      context.log('First document Id modified : ', restaurant[0].id);
      // the restaurant variable is an array where 1 or more modified documents can come, iterate and consume
      context.done();
    }
```

You can loop on the `restaurant` variable (the name maps to the name you defined in the `name` property in your config) and for each document, send an email.

Remember to have try/catch blocks within any loop in case one of the emails fails to send for whatever reason, the loop does continue with the rest. Log any errors, but avoid exiting the function if there is more documents to process.